# Inactive plugin warnings logged in log file

Tags: plugin-development, wp-debug

I have enabled WP_DEBUG in config.
I have also set WP_DEBUG_LOG to true
WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY is false.

I have one of the custom plugin that is inactive from the admin. But when i check the log file, there are php warnings etc logged about that plugin.

I am using wordpress rest API, and checking log. Am wondering how come inactive plugin logs error/warnings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this line in mu-plugins folder, which was adding the plugin to active list...
add_filter("pre_option_active_plugins", 'filter_loaded_plugins', 10, 2);